# Binding ComboBox to data source with 0 items initially, items added later causes ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, combobox

**UPDATE**

It appears this may be something else. There is a BindingList of accounts bound to a ListBox. When the user selects an account, their billing periods show up in the ComboBox (after which they can view the bills for each period). Before I even attempt to add an item to an empty list bound to the ComboBox, if I switch from an account that has loaded a pre-existing billing period, to one with no billing period, and then try to switch back, the same exception is thrown. The information below is for the scenario where I would switch to an account that does not have a pre-existing billing period, and attempt to add a new one. I've added some more code to show the binding for the ListBox, if it helps.

**END UPDATE**

I'm running into what seems to be a simple issue but I cannot figure out how to proceed. I have a `ComboBox` data bound to a `BindingList` (encapsulated by a `BindingSource`), containing billing period objects. The objects contain their own `BindingLists`, the contents of these lists are displayed in a grid (as bills). This way when the user selects a billing period, the grid reflects the correct bills for the period.

Here is the binding code:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(Controller, "Accounts");
listAccounts.DataSource = bs;
listAccounts.DisplayMember = "Name";

BindingSource source = new BindingSource(bs, "Periods");
comboPeriod.DataSource = source;
comboPeriod.DisplayMember = "DisplayPeriod";

BindingSource src = new BindingSource(source, "Bills");
gridPaymentSchedule.DataSource = src;
```

Not all accounts will have a pre-existing billing period, so the ComboBox will bind to an empty list. When I choose to add a billing period to these empty lists at a later point via `Periods.Add(period)`, I get the following exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.
```

So I did some searching on the web and I found that by adding an item to the data source of a ComboBox, even if it is empty it fires the SelectedIndexChanged event, however when it is empty a SelectedIndex of '0' is invalid because that index refers to the first item (which makes sense considering the exception text).

My problem then is this: I want to keep my binding behavior to maintain the ComboBox item changing the displayed bills. I can't think of a way of doing this or haven't figured one out where it doesn't trip over an initally empty data source. Ideally the behavior I am going for is that the ComboBox doesn't bind unless it's underlying data source is non-empty (to avoid this error).

- I tried suspending the binding for the binding source before adding my item, and then resuming, but this did not work.
- I tried disabling the ComboBox before adding and enabling after adding, to no avail.
- I tried deleting all the existing bindings before adding, and then re-adding them, but this failed as well. This last one I really can't figure out, because this is essentially simulating a "load" of the application for the first time when the bindings are first set.

The only other thing I can think of is to manually manage the ComboBox and data grid without binding but this will be a major pain. Is there no other way? There has to be!

Comment: Have you tried having the combobox unsubscribe from the selectionindexchanged event when adding the item, then resubscribing after?

Comment: It's hard o answer such question or help to find the problem. It's better to post a really simple code to reproduce the problem :)

Comment: @Tofystedeth I am not subscribing to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event myself, it is implicitly handled by the `ComboBox` class. I also checked the  designer code and do not see that Visual Studio subscribed an event handler. The only way I know to unsubscribe is like so: `combobox.SelectedIndexChanged -= eventHandler` but `eventHandler` is not already subscribed, so I am not sure it would work.

@RezaAghaei I will whip something up.

Comment: I was going to swear up and down that I had unsubscribed from implicit handlers before but I couldn't find an example where I done so, so comment retracted.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I think there is definitely something wrong with my code specifically, because in the reproduction test project I made, there is no issue. All the binding is happening in the same manner (building new BindingSources from previous ones).

Comment: @Fam The main benefit of creating a simple code to reproduce the problem is usually for you. Usually you find the problem yourself, or at least this guides you to the right direction or keeps you away from wrong direction. At the next step if you couldn't solve the problem yourself using the reproduction code, the community can reproduce the problem and help you.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Would it be against the rules to link the github repo where I am committing this code? It's my personal repo and I don't really see any other way to explain this behavior. Not exactly a "simple code" solution, but you will be able to run exactly the code I am running.

Comment: I don't know about the rules, maybe programmers.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask such question, but I think usually nobody here performs a code review to find the problem of complete project. Read about [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

My problem was similar but solution was different. I got this very same exception, with `ComboBox.DataSource` and `BindingList`, but only when debugging, and exceptions did not really stop the execution. When I just run the app there was no exception. I then enabled *"Enable Just My Code"* option in *Tools > Options > Debugging > General* and exceptions were gone.

Answer (score 0):

After having a friend look at the code, we tried the same code base on a different machine. It worked fine, with no changes. We tried a bunch of "fixes" on the original machine and finally it worked with some hacky fixes... Turns out we didn't need the hacky fixes at all, it was a caching issue with the build files.

Remember kids, REBUILD your project if you're having issues.

So, to note: there was no issue at all, my build files were out of date and were causing erroneous behavior.